# Create Dialog from Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I am trying to open a Dialog box when pressing on a button of a dialog box.
--> buttonPressed --> Dialog1 --> Dialog2

the first dialog box gets created as following:

```
(When button is pressed):

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);         //<-- dialog1 contains a button
final Button button1 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);  //<--in dialog1

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //A NEW DIALOG BOX SHOULD APPEAR HERE WHEN BUTTON1 GETS CLICKED
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

That's my code so far. What I've tried is to close the dialog box and then open up a new Dialog:

```
dialog.dismiss();
Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);

dialog.show();
```

But when trying to open a new Dialog box like this I get some error in the Coreographer.class. I assume that's because a closed dialog box can't create a new Dialog box. Now my question is, how would You open a Dialog box from another Dialog box by clicking on it's button?

Comment: `Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context);` Instead of context, try `YourActivityName.this`"

Comment: try dialog.dismiss() and dialog2.show() in new dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196886/show-one-progress-dialog-only-at-a-time-in-android/22197056#22197056

Comment: Your question says dialog.show() where it should say dialog2.show(). You cannot show a dialog after it has been dismissed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this on button click on dialog

```
Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
dialog.dismiss();
dialog2.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using context use

```
Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

Comment: Using context just works fine ;) My question was how to open a Dialog with an already existent Dialog

Comment: For what it's worth, you'd refer to the outer class with `.this` and not `.class`

Answer (score -1):

Try That

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);         //<-- dialog1 contains a button
final Button button1 = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.button1);  //<--in dialog1

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //A NEW DIALOG BOX SHOULD APPEAR HERE WHEN BUTTON1 GETS CLICKED
     Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
     dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
     dialog1.dismiss();
     dialog2.show();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```